# Javascript long term progress bar like Kickstarter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a solution or existing plugin which can achieve the same effect as Kickstarter or a crowd fund long term progression bar.

Existing solutions such as those I found here all relate to short term dynamic progress bars which display for users how much percent or time is left.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-progress-bar/page/2/

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

http://workshop.rs/2012/12/animated-progress-bar-in-4-lines-of-jquery/

Currently I'm calling four values via ajax:

```
var beginning_value = 0;
var end_value = 6199;
var spent_value = 3000;
var remaining_value = 3199;
```

When a user clicks on a button, the `spent_value` increases by 1 whilst `remaining_value` decreases by 1. I just need this to reflect in the progress bar.

Any solution or idea would be really helpful for me now.

Thanks

Comment: Those variables are nice and all, but where's the actual code?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to even start, so that's why I'm asking here. I mean the solutions all point to dynamic short term progress bars, I need to display this progress bar each time the page loads but with more long term values

Comment: Why don't you set one up in its default demo config at least and look at the documentation.  I mean, do you even jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic progress bar can be made like so:

```
<div style="height:32px;background:#ccc">
    <div style="height:32px;width:40%;background:blue"></div>
</div>
```

The critical part is the `width:40%` as this will be the percentage completion of your progress bar. You can define this width in your server-side code.

If you want JavaScript to update it, all you need to do is get that inner `div` (perhaps by giving it an ID you can select) and set its `.style.width` to the new percentage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the third link you yourself already provided for the basic code.
2. You don't need all of those variables.  The beginning value is always going to be zero.  You only need the end value and remaining value.
3. The number as a percentage to supply to your progress bar is (remaining_value/end_value)*100